# Issue with pushed .ipynb file not rendering correctly in GitHub

Tags: github, jupyter-notebook, formatting, format, rendering

**System:** WIN10

**IDE:** ANACONDA/Jupyter Lab

**Language:** Python version 3.7.3

**Library:** pandas version 1.0.1

**Data source/Location:** https://github.com/ahull002/P001.predictive.maintenance.logreg

**Dataset/File:** 2_Data_Understanding.ipynb

**User Story:**

I am having a conversion issue when trying to view .pynb files I have pushed to GitHub. They look crooked as if there is some sort of rendering issue. The markdown cells from Jupyter notebook are displaying horizontal and squeezed versus vertical and sliding up or down.

**Steps were taken:**

1. searched StackOverflow for rendering issues
2. search GitHub: Jupyter Notebook won't load on Github #3555
3. asked around but it is hard to articulate this issue versus just showing someone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with Github's Notebook renderer (Project Jupyter) does not have control over Github's renderer (it's close-sourced).

It's recommended that anyone having this issue use nbviewer to view notebooks on Github.

Reference:
https://github.com/ahull002/nbviewer